# Easy way to parse file for directives in C?

Tags: c, parsing

Is there an easy way to parse a file for a directive (as I can't think of a better word for it)?

I need to scan a file for `<!--#directive parameter=value -->`, copy the value, find the location and length where this directive was in the file, so it can be replaced with whatever.

I come from microcontrollers, and don't have a lot of experience with extra / full libraries.

Is there a better way to implement this than manually scanning it line by line? (I guess with ftell for position, fgets, and then parse with sscanf, fseek back to last position if it was a match).

Comment: You might want to look at regular expressions. GNU C has an [implementation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)

Comment: I'd go for flex/bison. not exactly easy to start with, though.

Comment: I would scan the file for the directives character by character, in the obvious way. Regexps are not suitable if this is a HTML-like file (which it seems to be?) since they can not be used to parse SGML like languages correctly.

Comment: Which libraries can you use? Or plain C and standard libs only?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression which can help:

```
<!--\s*#.+=(\S+)\s?-->
```

Group with index 1 in each match is your value.
You can test them here: https://regex101.com/

Also consider using high-level language for this. Here is a snippet in C# which prints all values from a text file:

```
var inputText = File.ReadAllText("D:\\myTextFile.txt");
var regex = new Regex("<!--\\s*#.+=(\\S+)\\s?-->");
var matches = regex.Matches(inputText);
foreach (var g in matches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups[1]))
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
```